# Issue with bind/unbind of <a>

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have an anchor tag that lives inside a draggable UI, which has a .click() function that fires if the anchor is clicked and the mouse moves more than 5 pixels, indicating the users intention to drag not follow the link.

I tried to put .unbind in the .mouseup, but it's preventing the .click() from firing at all. Ideas?

Code below:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
  var anchorPos = e.pageX - $('#fake').position().left;
  var distance = e.pageX - anchorPos;
  if (Math.abs(distance) > 5) {e.preventDefault();return false;}
});
```

And then:

```
$(document).one('mouseup', function () {
  $(document).unbind();
  $('a').unbind();
...
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple...

Comment: If you're just trying to prevent the default behavior (not following the link) than your first function should work on its own. Is the calculation working properly?

Comment: @Kroehre The first click works until it's unbound and then it stops firing ......  ugh, I just realized all I have to do is rebind it.

Comment: @JamesMontagne It's a container that gives illusion of space, so it's fake :)

Comment: If someone wants to post the answer now, I'll mark it lol

Comment: I believe you can just answer your own question and then accept it if you've figured it out yourself.

Comment: Sure, but not one gets points for that :) You guys were helpful, it's an easy way to be kind.

Comment: You shouldn't need to ever call unbind(). Leaving out the second function entirely should fix the issue...

Comment: @Kroehre Oh but I do, otherwise the anchor tag is unclickable for the duration of the visit. I only want the anchor unclickable during the mouseup of a drag event that started on the anchor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({ cancel: 'button' });
```

From: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-cancel

Comment: Hey! No I have not. I'll give it a shot. What I have now works, but no one submitted an answer :)